# Differentiable limit of a (uniformly convergent) sequence of differentiable function (again, but not exactly !)

Tags: derivatives, sequence-of-function

If one has a uniformly convergent sequence of differentiable functions $f_n$ (say from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$), we know that the limit $f$ is not always differentiable. Even if it is differentiable, the derivative $f'(x)$ is not necessarily the limit of the derivatives $f'_n(x)$.

But in all the counter-examples I know, there is a sequence $x_n$ (with the limit $x$) such that $f'(x)$ is the limit of $f'_n(x_n)$.

My question is : Is it always true ? 
I have tried to use Rolle's theorem, but did not succeed. Or do you know also a counter-example for this ? Thank you.

Comment: There are examples where $f_n$ are smooth but $f$ is not differentiable anywhere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function
Or are you looking specifically for examples where $f'$ exists but is not the limit of $f_n'$? I don't know any of those.

Comment: Thank you, there are such examples (for instance, with $\sin \frac{t}{n}$ for instance, even on Stack Exchange). My question is : if, even in this case, there is a positive weaker statement , that $f'(x)$ is not the limit of $f'_n (x)$, but is the limit of $f'_n(x_n)$ for a certain sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$.